# How to use Selenium Webdriver(Java) to simulate drag an element and drop it into an input box?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

In common browsers like Chrome, Firefox and IE, when you drag an element into an input box(input type="text"):

- If the element is an image(img href="image's url"), it's href attribute value will be filled into the input box;
- If the element is a text element(span，p...), it's text value will be filled into the input box.

I have invoked the Java API of selenium webdriver to simulate the action, but nothing is filled.

```
Actions builder = new Actions(driver);

//use dragAndDrop
builder.dragAndDrop(source, target).perform();

//use moveToElement,clickAndHold,release
builder.moveToElement(source, 10, 10).clickAndHold(source);
builder.moveToElement(target, 10, 10).release(source).perform();
```

I have tried many ways to simulate the same actions and expect to get the same result, it seems like the drag and drop actions are simulated, but I can't see the fill action.

Comment: Java isn't JavaScript!

Answer (score 0):

Try this way,

```
WebElement sourceLocator = driver.findElement(By.xpath("xpath")); //get source locator

WebElement targetLocator = driver.findElement(By.xpath("xpath")); //get target locator

Actions action = new Actions(driver);

action.dragAndDrop(sourceLocator, targetLocator).build().perform(); //perform drag and drop (from(sourceLocator) -> to(targetLocator))
```